# MySQL count takes too long with many join

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

In my project, I make 3 queries and one takes too much time.
I use doctrine 2 and PHP and to make the request I use the QueryBuilder.
I've got a list of vehicles (900 000 records), a list of clients (600 000 records), utilisateur (600 000 records) and _client_has_groupe_etablissement (600 000 records).
In my first query I count the number total of vehicles. it take 0.25s => Perfect.
My secound query allow to find vehicle by different filter with multiple joins. It take 0.5s => Perfect.
Here is the query :

```
SELECT [MANY THINGS] 
FROM vehicule v0_ 
INNER JOIN categorie_vehicule c1_ ON v0_.idCategorieVehicule = c1_.idCategorieVehicule 
INNER JOIN energie e2_ ON v0_.idEnergie = e2_.idEnergie 
LEFT JOIN vehicule_lastrdv v6_ ON (v6_.idVehicule = v0_.idVehicule) 
LEFT JOIN client c4_ ON v0_.idUtilisateur = c4_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN utilisateur u5_ ON c4_.idUtilisateur = u5_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN ​_client_has_groupe_etablissement t3_​ ON c4_.idUtilisateur = t3_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN groupe_etablissement g7_ ON t3_.idGroupeEtablissement = g7_.idGroupeEtablissement 
WHERE v0_.actifVehicule = 1 
ORDER BY v0_.idVehicule DESC 
LIMIT 207 
OFFSET 0;
```

The last query is the count of the total return rows of the previous request :

```
SELECT COUNT(v0_.idVehicule) AS sclr_0 
FROM vehicule v0_ 
INNER JOIN categorie_vehicule c1_ ON v0_.idCategorieVehicule = c1_.idCategorieVehicule 
INNER JOIN energie e2_ ON v0_.idEnergie = e2_.idEnergie 
LEFT JOIN vehicule_lastrdv v3_ ON v3_.idVehicule = v0_.idVehicule 
LEFT JOIN client c4_ ON v0_.idUtilisateur = c4_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN utilisateur u5_ ON c4_.idUtilisateur = u5_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN ​_client_has_groupe_etablissement t6_​ ON c4_.idUtilisateur = t6_.idUtilisateur 
LEFT JOIN groupe_etablissement g7_ ON t6_.idGroupeEtablissement = g7_.idGroupeEtablissement 
WHERE v0_.actifVehicule = 1;
```

But this query take 20s

Here is the explanation of this request, but all seems to be good

```
id  select_type table                   partitions  type?   possible_keys                                                         key                               key_len   ref                               rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     v0_                                 ref     IDX_D0599D4B9F7AC00B,IDX_D0599D4B323EB152,idx_vehicule_actifVehicule  idx_vehicule_actifVehicule        1         const                             440436  100.00  Using where
1   PRIMARY     e2_                                 eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                               PRIMARY                           4         r4-p19d.v0_.idEnergie             1       100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY     c1_                                 eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                               PRIMARY                           4         r4-p19d.v0_.idCategorieVehicule   1       100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>                          ref     <auto_key0>                                                           <auto_key0>                       5         r4-p19d.v0_.idVehicule            10      100.00  
1   PRIMARY     c4_                                 eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                               PRIMARY                           4         r4-p19d.v0_.idUtilisateur         1       100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY     u5_                                 eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                               PRIMARY                           4         r4-p19d.c4_.idUtilisateur         1       100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY     t3_                                 ref     PRIMARY,IDX_30B01ADE5D419CCB                                          PRIMARY                           4         r4-p19d.c4_.idUtilisateur         1       100.00  Using index
1   PRIMARY     g7_                                 eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                               PRIMARY                           4         r4-p19d.t3_.idGroupeEtablissement 1       100.00  Using index
2   DERIVED     rdv                                 index   PRIMARY,IDX_86645D0C4FFC60ED,idx_rdv_idRDV_dateRDV_idAgenda           idx_rdv_idRDV_dateRDV_idAgenda    17        981941                                     33.33  Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     agenda                              eq_ref  PRIMARY,IDX_2B41CD41EA190502                                          PRIMARY                           4         r4-p19d.rdv.idAgenda              1       100.00  Using where
2   DERIVED     etablissement                       eq_ref  PRIMARY                                                               PRIMARY                           4         r4-p19d.agenda.idEtablissement    1       100.00  
2   DERIVED     _vehicule_has_controle              ref     IDX_1EAA071A9F61066B                                                  IDX_1EAA071A9F61066B              5         r4-p19d.rdv.idRDV                 1       100.00
```

I would like to know how to reduce this execution time in MySQL directly or with doctrine.

I have already tried with `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`, but it takes the same time.
Also with countRows or count in doctrine

Comment: What are those derived tables at the bottom of the explain? I can't relate them back to any of the queries you posted. Out of them rdv seems to be big and has using temporary, using filesort in the extra column - these may take a long time.

Comment: But why do you need all these `LEFT JOIN`'s when you are not using data from them in count query?

Comment: @Shadow The derevied is because vehicule_lastrdv  is a view in MySQL. But this request does not take many time.

Comment: @Ilya Yarkovets I use all the left join for the second query to filter. A user can filter the list of vehicule. And i want to display the total number of vehicle and the total number of filter vehicule. That's why I use the same request to count. But I tried by adding SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS in the second query but this take the same time (20s)

Comment: Ok, but why you are not joining them "on demand"? I mean smth like this:
`if user has chosen some filter than we add needed join statement` (in pseudocode). And provided query would be slow just because there are too many large joined tables which are not needed at the moment. Using join's "on demand" will give you better performance when there are no filters chosen, but for the situtations when there are lot of them/all chosen you must either simplify query or use smth lighter, mayber like views for large table, or some result cache, or smth else. Hope it would help :)

Comment: As this is working but takes to much time I would recommend you to ask this question at our stack site specifically for [database administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: The view itself might not take much time, but in effect doing an unkeyed join between the views result set and the main query might take a substantial amount of time.

Comment: I will asked it in the other site. But I always have the problem unfortunatelly. When the user search, he search in all the database, there is no way to limit the search actually. So all the join are needed :/ And without the view it take also the same time :/ Thanks for your reply and if you have any other suggestions propose it

Comment: If the view doesn't affect the time, could you execute that SQL with the view taken out and post it and the EXPLAIN for it (which should be far easier to read without the derived tables).